# Close hamburger menu with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I close my hamburger menu when clicking on link, I need it for one page navigation. Menu works fine but just need a way to close it.
I have very little knowledge about JS.

I have this in HTML and CSS, don't have any JS:

HTML in index.html file

```
<nav>
<div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

<ul id="menu" class="navbar-collapse">
        <li><a href="#1">idi na 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">idi na 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">idi na 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS in style.css file

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
a:hover{
    color: #999999;
}
#menuToggle{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#menuToggle input{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span{
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
    opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#menuToggle span:first-child{
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2){
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
    background: #000000;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3){
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2){
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu{
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height:100vh;
    margin: -77px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li{
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul{
    transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
    opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) { 
    #menuToggle input {
        top: 2px;
        left: -5px;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Comment: I think this would work `document.querySelector('#menuToggle input')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `trigger` .

```js
$('#menu > li > a').on('click', function() {
  $("#menuToggle").find('input').trigger("click");
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
nav{
position:fixed;
z-index: 99999;
}
a{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color: #000000;
transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
a:hover{
color: #999999;
}
#menuToggle{
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
#menuToggle input{
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 32px;
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
left: -5px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span{
display: block;
width: 33px;
height: 4px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
position: relative;
background: #000000;
border-radius: 3px;
z-index: 1;
transform-origin: 4px 0px;
transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#menuToggle span:first-child{
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2){
transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span{
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
background: #000000;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3){
opacity: 0;
transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2){
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu{
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;    
position: absolute;
width: 100vw;
height:100vh;
margin: -77px 0 0 -50px;
padding: 50px;
padding-top: 125px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
list-style-type: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform: translate(-100%, 0);
transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li{
padding: 10px 0;
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul{
transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) { 
#menuToggle input {
top: 2px;
left: -5px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuToggle">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>

  <ul id="menu" class="navbar-collapse">
    <li><a href="#1">idi na 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">idi na 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">idi na 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Note: Don't forget to put your js code inside document.ready.*

```
$(function() {
 $('#menu > li > a').on('click', function() {
      $("#menuToggle").find('input').trigger("click");
    });
});
```